# Addressing elements by name defined in variable

Tags: javascript, variables, element

I have a form in my document (with name 'formName') and a few elements with names part text, followed by an ID, eg: an input with name 'model_'+z where z is an ID.

I need some way to address these elements, I am simply using bracket notation:

```
document.formName['model_'+z].value
```

but IE doesn't like this and giving me:

> Message:
>   'document.formName[...].value' is null
>   or not an object

but this solution works fine in other browsers.

What is the simplest way of addressing elements with names like these (half static text + half dynamic variable)?

Cheers

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well? The line you posted looks absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementsByName('model_'+z)[0]`

Comment: Isn't that tag name, not name attribute?

Answer (score 0):

If it is an ID and truly individual you can use `getElementsByID('z');`